# send html table row data to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a html table.I have put a button and when it press  particular row data will print as alert. But when click on separate cells this function execute.I need to stop it. Can you please help me to do this here I attach the code link

[This is jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/gojaxofe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: When you press Test Button it show the output but if you  click on separate column also give the output.I need to stop it and only button click will execute.

Comment: So you want click event on button only?

Comment: hi eveyone. i have a code. i need to get textboxes values when click on button, but when i am going to type on textbox it shows msg.

Comment: please create a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `on` and apply the scope to input button

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#myt tr').on("click","input[type='submit']",function(e) {
            alert($(this).parents("tr:first").text());
            e.preventDefault();
       });
 });
```

[**jsBIN Demo**](http://jsbin.com/gojaxofe/15/edit)

Comment: hi i changed the code,when i am going to each and every textbox it shows msg for me. here is my demo http://jsbin.com/sadalede/1/ please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link for your answer
[Click here for demo](http://jsbin.com/gojaxofe/7#)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myt tr td input').click(function(event) {
                   alert($(this).parents('tr').text());
                });
});
```

Jquery code this will work please try it

Comment: don't copy paste dear :)

Comment: Hey where i have copied?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi please explain me

Comment: I have posted this before anyone ;-)

Comment: Can you see the difference between urs and me

Comment: I have Seen and one more person downvoted your ans.

Comment: Why you downvote? i just wanted this are you following other's ?

Comment: I don't downvoted you never

Comment: Thank You Very Much .It is nice help Thank You

Comment: don't forget to mark it answer if u get ur solution

Answer (score 0):

```
     $('#myt input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
           alert($(this).parents().text());
        });
```

And ID should be unique

Answer (score 0):

Change your js function to below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myt input[type="submit"]').click(function(event) {
      alert($(this).parents('tr').text());
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hA423/50/

Comment: Why did you paste an empty fiddle?

Comment: By mistake i posted a wrong link of fiddle :D